# Android Battery Optimization

Tags: android

I am developing an app that has a foreground service and am trying to detect when there are network changes to see when I can and cannot connect. With Power Saving (Samsung S6) disabled, listening to ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts works perfectly. However, when I enable power saving, I can lose background data and the broadcast no longer tells me anything.

I suspect it is related to Doze so I tried to listen to PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED but it is never fired.

If I request Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS my problem goes away, but Google are pulling apps from the play store for requesting this. Any ideas what is causing me to lose network connection and how I can successfully listen to it coming and going?

Answer (score 0):

The user have to disable the battery optimizations.
You can start the screen for the user with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

So prompt the user to disable the battery optimizations and start this intent above.